# How would you create a WPF control using the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm

So I'm having trobule figuring out the best way to use the MVVM pattern while creating a WPF control dynamically within
my code. Would this even make sense or is it better to avoid the MVVM pattern all together?

If it does make sense then please share code examples of the view model.

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you're wanting dynamic control creation?

Comment: DataTemplate.  Search, learn.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you're using MVVM, controls will only be created "dynamically" in response to the data changing.  If you have an `ItemsControl` bound to a collection, for example, the controls to represent the items will automatically be created for you.

If you're talking about making a custom control *in general*, custom controls are really "pure view", so MVVM doens't really make sense in this scenario.  The main goal of creating a custom control is to build it in a way so that it can be *used* by code developed with MVVM, which typically means building the control with proper Dependency Properties (so data binding works properly), etc.